# Ideal intersection in Boolean polynomial ring

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, computer-algebra-systems

I'm trying to calculate

$ \langle x,y,z\rangle  \cap \langle x+1,y+1,z+1\rangle  $

in the ring of Boolean polynomials. In CoCoA initially I set the ring as

```
Use XYZ ::= QQ[x,y,z];
```

(which is the default ring anyway). Then,

```
I := ideal(x,y,z);
J:=ideal(x+1,y+1,z+1);
intersection(I,J);
```

outputs

```
ideal(y -z, x -z, z^2 +z)
```

Now, in a Boolean ring multiplication is idempotent and addition is cancellative, so I'm expecting `z^2+z` gone. Yet, setting

```
Use BXYZ := Z/(2)(x,y,z);
```

or

```
Use BXYZ := ZZ/(2)(x,y,z);
```

didn't change the ideal intersection. What is correct way to set the ring so that the answer is

```
ideal(y+z, x+z)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks a little bit like you believe that $z^2$ ought to be $z$, and then $z^2+z=0$.

It appears you are working in the polynomial ring $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)[x,y,z]$. This is certainly a ring of characteristic $2$, but it is not a Boolean ring at all. All the powers of $x$, all the powers of $y$ and all the powers of $z$ are distinct.

Calling these "Boolean polynomials" seems somewhat double edged for this reason. The polynomials are not themselves boolean. In fact $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)[x,y,z]$ is a domain and the only idempotent elements are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Why $Z/2Z$ is not a boolean ring? Certainly, $0*0=0$ and $1*1=1$. Then, we consider ring of all polynomials over $Z/2Z$, which should be the same as all polynomials over boolean ring? To express my question differently: what boolean ring axiom $Z/2Z$ doesn't honor?

Comment: In the last paragraph, are you implying that we could have two isomorphic rings (Z/2Z <--> Boolean), and yet rings of polynomials over them are not? Or you just assert that Z/2Z <-/-> Boolean

Comment: @TegiriNenashi $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ **is** a Boolean ring, and I never claimed otherwise.  I said $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)[x,y,z]$ **is not** a Boolean ring precisely because the variables are not idempotent.

Comment: I'm confused, how a variable from Boolean ring is allowed to be not idempotent. This sounds like a technicality, a failure of Boolean ring to communicate its property to polynomial extension.

Comment: @TegiriNenashi you can even see that it does not work for one variable. $F[x]$ is an integral domain for any field F, including the field of two elements. Polynomial rings over Boolean rings are simply not Boolean rings

Comment: On sage reference page I have found that ring of boolean polynomials is $F2[x_1,...,x_n]/ \langle x_1^2+x_1,...,x_n^2+x_n\rangle$, so I'm marking your answer as accepted

Comment: @TegiriNenashi Yes, that is different, that is forcing each variable to be idempotent. If you have $F_2[x]/(x^2-x)$, you can compute that it has four elements of the form $ax+b$ for $a,b\in F_2$. $F_2[x,y]/(x^2-x,y^2-y)$ will have eight elements, etc. They are sort of "boolean polynomials" but it is not really that helpful of a term. Lots of rings are quotients of polynomial rings, after all..